# Convert Oracle Wallet PKCS12 to JKS

Tags: oracle, keystore, jks, pkcs#12, oracle-wallet

I have a service that must be configured to connect to a database using Oracle Wallet. However, the program cannot use the standard PKCS12 format created by the Oracle mkstore -wrl commands. Guidance from the vendor is to convert the PKCS12 store to a jks file. They even kindly provide instructions on how to do so.

```
> orapki wallet pkcs12_to_jks -wallet ewallet.p12 -pwd 'abc123' -jksKeyStoreLoc test_wallet.jks -jksKeyStorepwd 'abc123'

> orapki wallet display -wallet test_wallet.jks -pwd 'abc123'

Oracle PKI Tool Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0
Copyright (c) 2004, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Length is too big: takes 109 bytes

> ls -l *wallet*

-rw-r--r--. 1  17501 Aug  2 12:51 cwallet.sso
-rw-r--r--. 1  17456 Aug  2 12:51 ewallet.p12
-rw-------. 1     32 Sep  2 13:30 test_wallet.jks
```

Unfortunately the program we're using can only use wallet if the keystore is in a jks format. But something seems to be going horribly wrong during creation of the wallet. The size is only 32 bytes which leads me to beleive the pcks12_to_jks command never worked in the first place. Looking for any help, insight. Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure whether something like this exists, but there is oracle-wallet-recover tool on GH, you can programmatically extract all the information from Oracle wallet - and create at least a new wallet.

Comment: That's something I can take a look at. The chief issue I'm having is the orapki pkcs12_to_jks command is not producing a well-behaved jks export. Appreciate you taking the time to reply! I'll try anything :)